# Compare 2 method's performance

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, performance-testing

I have the following:

```
public class Logger
{
    public static void LogStartMethod(MethodBase method)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Method '{1}' started", DateTime.Now, method.Name);
    }

    public static void LogStartMethod1()
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        MethodBase method = stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod();
        LogStartMethod(method);
    }

    public static void LogStartMethod2()
    {
        MethodBase method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
        LogStartMethod(method);
    }
}
```

I would like to identify the most performant method between LogStartMethod1 or LogStartMethod2...

Let's make abstraction of what that concrete method does, but is there a tool (online, or Visual Studio add-in) able to compare the performance of 2 methods?

I now that there are a lot of commercial performance profilers... and we should pay or use Visual Studio Ultimate to have a performance tool for a entire solution....

I would like just to compare 2 methods, it's all...

Comment: `Performance` is entirely subjective.  Speed? Memory usage? Memory leakage? CPU usage?

Comment: speed... and if possible memory usage, why not, but speed is important.

Comment: Performance Analysis is also included in Visual Studio Premium.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Do you just want to output the calling method?

Comment: @Serge had a thought last night, _be careful_ when analyzing the stack at runtime. Stack traces you get in release mode may be shorter. This is because the compiler will tend to in-line smaller methods (like property accessors). Do not rely on the output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you now that anything that assembles a stack trace will be slower than *similar*(tm) code that does not.

The fastest way to grab the calling methods name is using the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName` attribute. When you compile the code, the compile inserts the method name as a string literal. It is very quick but requires C# .5

This is my tried and tested perf code with sample methods thrown in to demonstrates the issue:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Action> tasks = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        tasks.Add("Task 1", Task1);
        tasks.Add("Task 2", Task2);
        tasks.Add("Task 3", Task3);

        string input = "This is a sample string";
        int count = 9999;

        Console.Write("Warming up...");
        foreach (var item in tasks.Values)
        {
            item();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var item in tasks)
        {
            var time = RunPerf(item.Key, count, item.Value);
            results.Add(string.Format("{0}\t\t{1}", item.Key, time));
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("RESULTS");
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Task1()
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        MethodBase method = stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod();
        LogStartMethod(method);
    }

    public static void Task2()
    {
        MethodBase method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
        LogStartMethod(method);
    }

    public static void Task3()
    {
        LogStartMethod();
    }

    public static void LogStartMethod(MethodBase method)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Method '{1}' started", DateTime.Now, method.Name);
    }
    public static void LogStartMethod([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]string methodName = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Method '{1}' started", DateTime.Now, methodName);
    }

    static TimeSpan RunPerf(string name, int count, Action action)
    {
        var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Starting perf for {0}. {1} times", name, count));

        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            action();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} completed in {1}", name, sw.Elapsed));

        return sw.Elapsed;
    }
}
```

**Note. Be sure to run this code in release. It *requires* C#5. I recommend using a .net 4.5 project**

```
RESULTS
Task 1          00:00:00.7226149
Task 2          00:00:00.5001454
Task 3          00:00:00.4690296
```

Comment: In fact, I would just liked to reduce the code... If I begin a method just by "LogStart();" and inside "stackTrace.GetFrame(1)" identifies the caller is less to write that "method = GetCurrentMethod()" and then "LogStart(method)"... but I see I lose some performance for the simplicity...

Comment: @Serge a further update with a 3rd task. Check out the code, it is magic.

Comment: Very interesyting this Task3...! Good Job.... Unfortunately my project is in .NET 3.5, but I will use this attribute for other projects...

Answer (score 5):

The `StopWatch` class can measure speed.
call `StopWatch.Start` before your test, and `StopWatch.Stop` afterwards.

Just remember to run the speed test in release mode, not debug mode.

Comment: So, to test my 2 methods, I should create a new project, put my class there, use the StopWatch before and after, use the release mode, output the result... It's so classic that I thought maybe somebody published something like this online...:-/

Comment: @Serge: its terribly easy to do, why would you spend time searching for and then downloading, and then modifying this kind of code when you can write it yourself in *much* less time?

Answer (score 1):

VS 12 Ultimate: check out menu item `ANALYZE & Start Performance Analysis` --- it delivers interesting feedback and not only related to 2 methods --- have tried it this week and the result was really fruitful for both current state and future direction of some coding issues.

Comment: well, but usually a programme includes more than 2 methods ;-)

Comment: I have to make choice between 2 methods. So I asked not how to fly to the moon, but just how to build a paper plane.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using simply *[Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* on two solutions, one using method `LogStartMethod1` and second using `LogStartMethod2`. Call this method for a few minutes continuously, and watch counters like `% Processor Time` and `.NET CLR Memory` for running process and measure of course a total number of method executions. Then you will see time processing difference along with difference in both CPU and memory consumption.